# How to update the 3rd element of nested elements (JSON like)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a MySQL table as follow:

```
|| ID || Name || handling                             || enabled || 
|| 1  || bob  || { 2 { 4, 7, 0.2 } 7 { 20.102, 3 } }  || 1       ||
|| 2  || abc  || { 6 { 4, 9, 0.6 } 7 { 20.102, 83 } } || 1       ||
|| 3  || xyz  || { 2 { 4, 78, 0.2 } 7 { 20.102, 3 } } || 1       ||
```

I'm trying to find a way to do the following trick via an SQL query:

The third number there (7 for id 1, 9 for id 2, 78 for id 3) has to be changed to '30'. I'd do it all manually, but it's a table of approx. 5000 rows. And I "could" make a loop in c++ to do it all, but for some technical reasons, I rather have a SQL query.

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid JSON

Comment: It probably isn't. I just made it up :P. But 'arturro''s response below seems like it will do the trick for what I need.

Comment: MySQL as some other database has a special support for JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Much more precise now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the part to replace is always between first and second comma then you can do some string slicing, like this:

to change text between 1 and 2 comma:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE6
SET A = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A,',',1),',','30',SUBSTRING(A, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A,',',2))+1));
```

to change text between 7 and 8 comma:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE6
SET A = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A,',',7),',','30',SUBSTRING(A, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A,',',8))+1));
```

Comment: What if the part to replace is between the 7th and 8th comma?

Comment: I fixed it. Example in the answer.

Comment: Will test for you later when I get home. :) Thanks.

Comment: Worked 100% as expected. This saved my life. Thanks.